# Mongo shell query timing out at 90 seconds

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I am using mongodb via the mongo shell to query a large collection.  For some reason after 90 seconds the mongo shell seems to be stopping my query and nothing is returned.

I have tried the following two commands but neither will return anything.  After 90 seconds it just gives me a new line that I can type in another command.

db.cards.find("Field":"Something").maxTimeMS(9999999)
db.cards.find("Field":"Something").addOption(DBQuery.Option.tailable)

db.cards.find() return results, but anything with parameters is timing out at exactly 90 seconds and nothing is being returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `db.cards.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout);`. How many documents do you have in the cards collection?

Answer (score 2):

Given the level of detail in your question, I am going to focus on 'query a large collection' and guess that your are using the MMAPv1 storage engine, with no index coverage on your query.

**Are you disk bound?**

Given the above assumptions, you could be cycling data between RAM and disk. Mongo has a default 100MB RAM limit, so if your query has to examine a lot of documents (no index coverage), paging data from disk to RAM could be the culprit. I have heard of mongo shell acting as you describe or locking/terminating when memory constraints are exceeded.

32bit systems can also impose severe memory limits for large collections.

You could look at your OS specific disk activity monitor to get a clue into whether this is your problem.

**Just how large is your collection?**

Next, how big is your collection? You can `show collections` and see the physical size of the collection and also `db.cards.count()` to see your record count. This helps quantify "large collection".

NOTE: you might need the mongo-hacker extensions to see collection disk use in show collections.

**Mongo shell investigation**

Within the mongo shell, you have a couple more places to look.
By default, mongo will log slow queries (> 100ms). After your 90 sec timeout:

```
db.adminCommand({getLog: "global" })
```

and look for slow query log entries.

Next look at your winning query plan.

```
var e = db.cards.explain()
e.find("Field":"Something")
```

I am guessing you will see

```
"stage": "COLLSCAN",
```

Which means you are doing a full collection scan and you need index coverage for your query (good idea for queries and sorts).

**Suggestions**

You should have at least partial index coverage on any production query. A proper index should solve your problem (assuming you don't have documents > 16MB).

Another approach (that I don't recommend - indexing is better) is to use a cursor instead

```
var cursor = db.cards.find("Field":"Something")
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  print(tojson(cursor.next()));
}
```

Depending on the root cause, this may work for you.